# I don't want to see into file-output the last character

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){

FILE *fp;
if((fp=fopen("Example.txt", "r"))== NULL){
    printf("Errore apertura file");
    exit(0);
}
char s[50];
int i=0;
while(!feof(fp)){
if(!feof(fp)){
s[i++]=fgetc(fp);
    }
}
s[i]='\0';
fclose(fp);
char nome[20];
printf("Inserisci il nome che vuoi dare al file di uscita\n");
//fgets(nome,20,stdin);
scanf("%s",& nome);
char tipo[5]=".txt";
strcat(nome,tipo);
if((fp=fopen(nome,"w"))== NULL){
    printf("Errore apertura file");
    exit(0);
}
fputs(s, fp);
fclose(fp);
return 0;  
}
```

The output file over the string is even printed an abnormal character, how can I not see it?
The output is "string"+'ÿ'`
The problem is only in the output file and not in the capture.

Comment: It has to be `scanf("%s", nome);`

Comment: And *never* use `feof`. Always check for `EOF` manually.

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for a discussion of why using `feof()` is wrong.  What you are seeing is normal behaviour for a code set such as CP1252 or ISO 8859-1 where code point 0xFF is U+00FF, LATIN LOWER CASE LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS (ÿ).  You shouldn't assign the result of `fgetc(fp)` to a `char`; you should check whether the `int` value is EOF before using it as a character.

Answer (score 0):

Your input loop should be:

```
char s[50];
int i=0;
int c;
while (i < (50 - 1) && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    s[i++] = c;
s[i] = '\0';
```

Or even:

```
char s[50];
int i;
int c;
for (i = 0; i < (50 - 1) && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF; i++)
    s[i] = c;
s[i] = '\0';
```

These avoid buffer overflow and do not try to store EOF in the array `s`.  They also doesn't use `feof()`; you seldom need to use it, and when you do, it is after a loop has ended and you need to distinguish between EOF and a read error (see also `ferror()`).

Comment: thanks, good it's go very well, if i want delate the numer [50] how I can do?

Comment: Which 50?   The first needs to be replaced by some suitably large number.  The second could be replaced by `sizeof(s)`.